# Died and lost my jewel, can I get another one?

Tags: a-dark-room

I had a jewel than I died and lost it now I can not find it anywhere. 
I need it so I can give it to the frog guy. 
Is there a way to get one more jewel? 
I have been everywhere regarding the map.

Answer (score 1):

I found a jewel in a trap very early in the game (Before I even had my compass). This leads me to believe you could find more in a similar way.

Answer (score 0):

there are more than one jewels, you'll just have to wait until you either find one or get one in your traps.

Answer (score 0):

Just got jewels today. Once you go everywhere on the map (except the swamp/cabin place that needs the jewel) the story, which is obtained by carting wood, will lead you to get 5 jewels for free. If you lost all 5 of those, your'e probably in bad shape, but if you didn't get the 5 jewels, make sure everything on the map is even a safe place (P) or a mine (I, C, S) Then the story should continue to the jewels.